# Calculating the average of value in group of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, calculated-columns

I have an **Excel** sheet in this format.

[image: Excel Sheet]

You can see that there are groups of dates, and there is a column `Present` with boolean values. I want to find the percentage of `Yes` in the `Present` field. If this was SQL, I would have done easily. I have a few questions in Excel.

1. Is this feasible?
2. What kind of formula should I use?
3. Should I use macros for these or just formulae would do?
4. Will I be able to fill the column automatically, without I merging cells each and every time manually?

I had played around with `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF`, but didn't work for me. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use one `COUNTIF` and one `COUNTIFS`

In the first cell containing the percentage for instance, you could use:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"YES")/COUNTIF(A:A,A2)
```

Assuming that `1-May-13` is in A2 and `Yes` is in B2.

`COUNTIFS` uses multiple criteria. Here, it counts only if the date in A1 is `1-May-13` and the value in B2 is `Yes`.

The `COUNTIF` just counts the number of times the date appears.

You can then format the column as a percentage.

It will be difficult I think with the merging and unmerging cells though.

Comment: OKay... And you are *assuming* that there will be `Yes` in one cell right? Even that is unpredictable. The table is a huge set of rows.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Lets say I don't have the rows merged in column `C`. Also, the first value, i.e., `B2` can even be `NO`, rather `YES`.

Comment: I actually missed the part about having `NO` before. I edited the formula to fix that. -- I don't understand what you mean in your first question "And you are assuming that there will be `Yes` in one cell right? Even that is unpredictable" Do you have anything besides `YES` and `NO` that you are counting?

Comment: You solved it in your edit by giving an `YES` in the `COUNTIFS`. Thanks. If at all any issues arise, can I update in this answer?

Comment: Uh... sure I guess! The merging and unmerging part is the tricky part, and I don't know how to deal with that one. You could perhaps have a new sheet altogether with only the dates appearing once and the percentages.

Comment: Dude, it works even if you merge cells. No worries. :) At first we had the sheets per day separately. We made it into single sheet.